# Guide for working with Linux thread priorities and scheduling policies?

Tags: linux, multithreading, documentation, conventions, thread-priority

I'm having trouble getting the hang of thread(/process) prioritization on Linux, scheduling policy selection, what to choose when and how, and what the exact effects are.

Is there any documentation (like a guide) somewhere, preferably with concrete examples and timelines, which I could consult?

Comment: @Gray: Well you essentially told me not to bother... and I would have liked something which does bother with the details. I have upvoted you now, though, which I probably should have done earlier.

Comment: @Gray: By that document I shouldn't accept your answer. But it might be the case that the question needs to be closed as off-topic for asking for an off-site resource :-(

Answer (score 3):

> I'm having trouble getting the hang of thread(/process) prioritization on Linux, scheduling policy selection

The prioritization works by utilizing the underlying OS' thread and process priorities and it is hard to generalize about the specifics of it from the standpoint of documentation which may be why you've not found guides online.

My recommendation is (frankly) to not bother with thread priorities.  I've done a large amount of threaded programming and I've never found the need to do anything but the default prioritization.  About the only time thread prioritization will make a difference is if all of the threads are completely CPU bound and you want one task or another to get more cycles.

In addition, I'm pretty sure that under Linux at least, this isn't about preemption but more about run frequency.  Many thread implementations use a priority scheduling queue so higher frequency threads get preference with logic in there to avoid starving the lower frequency threads.  This means that any IO or other blocking operation is going to cause a lower priority thread to run and get its time slice.

This page is a [good example of the complexities](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml) of the issue.  To quote:

> As can be seen, thread priorities 1-8 end up with a practically equal share of the CPU, whilst priorities 9 and 10 get a vastly greater share (though with essentially no difference between 9 and 10). The version tested was Java 6 Update 10. For what it's worth, I repeated the experiment on a dual core machine running Vista, and the shape of the resulting graph is the same. My best guess for the special behaviour of priorities 9 and 10 is that THREAD_PRIORITY_HIGHEST in a foreground window has just enough priority for certain other special treatment by the scheduler to kick in (for example, threads of internal priority 14 and above have their full quantum replenished after a wait, whereas lower priorities have them reduced by 1).

If you must use thread priorities then to you may have to write some test programs to understand how your architecture utilizes them.

Comment: I'm in exactly the single exception you mentioned... nothing is I/O bound, but some threads need to be scheduled very soon after becoming ready, while others not so much.

Comment: I've added some details @einpoklum to my answer to show you some testing done on the subject.  It's really a difficult issue.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly: I can get the effect of having a binary distinction between "high priority" and "low priority" threads, so that the former basically always preempt the latter, but beyond this rough distinction it's tricky/inconsistent/not worth exploring?

Comment: Even that depends on your architecture @einpoklum.  Certainly worth a try however.  If you need to be sure, you might consider writing some test software and count long increments or something in a loop until some timer expires or something and then compare priority to number of ticks.

Comment: One thing to consider @einpoklum is to not fork as many of the low priority threads.  Use a thread-pool and reduce the number of concurrently running tasks to match your CPU architecture.  Maybe submit the high priority ones first so they finish first and the low priority ones later.

Comment: Already doing that. But it's a thin line between over- and under-subscription...

Comment: Anyone want to explain the downvote?

Comment: It wasn't me, so no...