# How long does it take to change a thread's priority in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduler

What I can't find is any statement on whether changing a thread's priority is a costly operation, time-wise. I would like to do it frequently, but if each switch carries a significant time penalty it is probably not worth the trouble.

Comment: Thread priority is just a suggestion for system scheduler about how it should deal CPU time between threads. Setting the priority is as costly as setting one variable (potentially via JNA). Changed priority will take effect after next time dealing happens, so how long will it take for change to have an effect is unspecified. If you change priority frequently, you may potentially end up with situation where next change comes before last change had any effect.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - If a thread's priority is changed to higher than any currently running thread, that now higher priority thread will immediately start running, which would result in an immediate context switch if a core is not currently idle.

Comment: @rcgldr, I think this is anecdotal. There is nothing saying that setting priority must trigger a reschedule operation. At least nothing close to Thread documentation in JDK. That said, if thread will immediately run, then this is a relatively costly operation, as that requires a context switch.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what problem are you hoping to solve by changing thread priorities so often?

Comment: Setting the thread priority is a *system call*, guys. That's quite a bit more than setting one variable. But there is little to be gained by fiddling with them.

Comment: To answer @james large: my app examines a full-speed stream of incoming Bluetooth data packets. Some are invalid and can be ignored. Others are high-priority and need immediate attention, with significant computation. My thought was to receive the packets at normal priority, then kick it up if the packet needed handling.

Comment: "Kick it up if ..." doesn't make sense to me.  If the next packet that arrives might need prompt attention, then your packet thread should _wait_ at high priority.  If it waits at low priority, there could be a substantial delay between when the packet arrives and when the thread actually wakes up to deal with it.  Then, let's say a packet arrives, and your high-priority thread realizes that the packet is unimportant.  It should _stay_ at high priority, clean up whatever it has to clean up, so that it can be ready ASAP to handle the _next_ packet, which might be an important one.

Comment: @james large It sounds like you are saying the thread should always have high priority, but Bluetooth packets don't arrive that fast (I think). The increase in thread priority was to let the packets be digested quickly, not so much to receive them instantaneously. Food for thought.

Comment: @rcgldr It isn't how it would work on any operating system that wasn't fully pre-emptive.

Comment: "Little to be gsined" as @EJP says is right. Also there's the risk of priority inversion bugs.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov - Changing the priority of a ready to run thread: WIndows - move a node (remove, insert) a node from one priority indexed run queue to another; Linux (current versions) move a node (remove, insert) within a red-black tree. For both Windows and Linux, preemption may occur due to the priority change (not at the next time slice).

Comment: @EJP - I'm not aware of any preemptive operating systems that only perform context switches on time slice boundaries. All of the operating systems I'm aware of can perform user mode context switches due to system calls or interrupt at the time of the system call or interrupt. The term "fully preemptive" is sometimes used in reference to [preemptive kernels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_preemption), where context switches can occur in kernel mode in addition to user mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What I can't find is any statement on whether changing a thread's priority is a costly operation, time-wise. I would like to do it frequently, but if each switch carries a significant time penalty it is probably not worth the trouble.

Any answer here is going to be very OS dependent.  I suspect with most Unix variants that the answer is no, it's not costly.  It may require some sort of data synchronization but otherwise it is just setting a value on the thread's administrative information.  I suspect that there is no rescheduling of the threads as discussed in the comments.

That said, without knowing more about your particular use case, I doubt it is going to be worth the trouble.  As I say in the answer listed below, about the only time thread prioritization will make a difference is if all of the threads are completely CPU bound and you want one task or another to get more cycles.

Also, thread priorities are very non-linear and small changes to them may have little to no effect so any overhead incurred in setting the thread priorities will overwhelm any benefits gained by changing them.

See my answer here:
[Guide for working with Linux thread priorities and scheduling policies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28181758/guide-for-working-with-linux-thread-priorities-and-scheduling-policies/28194922#28194922)

Also, check out this article about [Java thread priorities](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/priority_what.shtml) and some real life testing of them under Linux.  To quote:

> As can be seen, thread priorities 1-8 end up with a practically equal share of the CPU, whilst priorities 9 and 10 get a vastly greater share (though with essentially no difference between 9 and 10). The version tested was Java 6 Update 10.

Comment: Linux switched from using priority indexed run queues to a red-black tree. Assuming the affected thread is ready to run, changing priority involves moving a node (remove, insert) within the red-black tree.

Comment: For this app, using a higher priority thread to receive the data, and lower priority thread(s) to process the data, would allow the receiving thread to preempt the processing thread(s) to avoid loss of data. I don't see a need for dynamic priority changes though.

Answer (score -1):

In the case of Windows, a call to SetThreadPriority to change the priority of a ready to run thread is a system call that will move the thread from it's current priority ready queue to a different priority ready queue, which is more costly than just setting some value in a thread object.

If SetThreadPriority is used to increase the priority of a thread, and if that results in the now higher priority thread preempting a lower priority thread, the preemption occurs at call time, not at the next time slice.

Ready queues are mentioned here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682105(v=vs.85).aspx

Context switching related to a priority change is mentioned here: "The following events might require thread dispatching ... **A thread’s priority changes**, either because of a system service call or because Windows itself changes the priority value." and "Preemption ... a lower-priority thread is preempted when a higher-priority thread becomes ready to run. This situation might occur for a couple of reasons: A higher-priority thread’s wait completes ... **A thread priority is increased or decreased.**" Ready queues are also mentioned: "Windows multiprocessor systems have per-processor dispatcher ready queues"

https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2233328&seqNum=7

I asked about this at MSDN forums. The fourth post agrees with the sequence I mention in the first and third post in this thread:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d4d40f9b-bfc9-439f-8a76-71cc5392669f/setthreadpriority-to-higher-priority-is-context-switch-immediate?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

---

In the case of current versions of Linux, run queues indexed by priority were replaced by a red-black tree. Changing a thread's priority would involve removal and reinsertion of a thread object within the red-black tree. Preemption would occur if the thread object is moved sufficiently to the "left" of the red-black tree.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-completely-fair-scheduler

---

In response to the comments about the app that "examines a full-speed stream of incoming Bluetooth data packets", the receiving thread should be highest priority, hopefully spending most of its time not running while waiting for the reception of a packet. The high priority packets would be queued up to be processed by another thread just lower in priority than the receiving thread. Multiple processing threads could take advantage of multiple cores if needed.

Comment: *Non sequitur*. There's nothing there that says the higher priority thread will start running immediately. It explicilty says that the context switch occurs when 'a thread with a higher priority *has become ready* to run'.

Comment: The statement 'moves it to a higher prior ready queue' is not consistent with the statement 'runs immediately'. If there is a thread already on the new ready queue it will run first, and if there is a ready thread with even higher priority it will run before that, or keep running.

Comment: Exactly. So fix your answer, and provide a citation that agrees with it. But none of this actually answers the question. And another SO answer doesn't count as a citation.

Comment: @EJP - I updated my answer once again. I've have a pending question at MSDN forums for this specific case, and will update when I get a reply.